# How to implement diacritics in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, diacritics

I need a help getting words from a .txt file which also contains diacritics. (So there are words containing ěščř etc. Btw that's czech diacritics if that helps.)
My function gets words I type, but it won't get words I type in console containing diacritics.
I think I have to set something in my Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 but I'm not sure what and where. In case I'm wrong, there's the function.

```
bool find(char typedword[50])
{
  bool found = false;
  char * word = new char [50];
  fstream dictionary;
  dictionary.open("Dictionary.txt", ios::in);
  while (dictionary >> word)
  {
    if (strcmp(typedword, word) == 0)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

  }
  dictionary.close();
  if (found == true)
      return true;
  else
      return false;
}
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You may need to use wide chars.

Comment: If the console is only taking the `ascii` character set then you won't be able to input characters from another character set. hodně štěstí

Comment: Well, it's just Windows 7 console and my Windows settings are czech, so it should be able to read this character set, right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamenick%C3%BD_encoding

Comment: What does `chcp` (without arguments) say?

Comment: And what is the hex value of the `typedword`, and the values you read from the dictionary?  I have no problem inputting CP852 on my machine.  The input characters are in a special Windows encoding, however; if your dictionary uses the same encoding, then you should have no problem.  If it doesn't, you'll have to transcode either the dictionary entries or your input, so that they both use the same encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need locale support, so that sequences of combining characters and the composite equivalent compare equal.

The portable way is `setlocale` and use `strcoll` instead of `strcmp`.

The Windows way is to use `CompareStringEx` (which automatically uses OS locale settings) instead of `strcmp`.  `NormalizeString` may also be helpful.

Comment: Disregard my (deleted) answer, this one actually makes sense. +1

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I'm using `setlocal` the wrong way or it just doesn't work for me. I added `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` to my function and replaced `strcmp` with `strcoll` and still it doesn't find words with diacritics in my .txt file.

Comment: @ThePopa611: Hmm, it seems like that should automatically set the locale.  Are you running Windows with a Czech locale?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I guess so, everything's czech here. I haven't tried the CompareStringEx function yet, so I'll try that, that could work. Thank you for your answer, it anyway got me new info about some new functions!

Comment: Does he even get the characters?  It tried changing my code page to 65001, and my keyboard to French, and the program just stopped when I entered a line with an accented character.  With the default code page (850 on my machine), it worked, but I got some very unexpected codes.  (Unexpected for me, anyway.)

Comment: If all he's interested in is Czech, maybe just using `chcp 1250` in the console window, before starting his program, is all he needs.

Comment: Well now I tried some stuff and the problem is that when I type in "Abatyše" and then call `cout << word;` it shows "Abatyçe".